# Thymeleaf page if condition checking possible?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf html page if checking is possible?

how to check this condition in thymeleaf..

i tried this but not working

```
<tr th:each="s : ${patterns}">
<h3><p th:text="${s.questionPattern}" /></h3>

<tr th:each="q : ${questions}">

<!--This checking is possible ? -->    

<div th:if="${#s.questionPattern == q.questionPattern.questionPattern}">  

<p><input type="text"  th:text="${q.questionName}" /></div>  
</p>
</tr>
</tr>
```

i know this is not the right way

if u know the answer please share..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Thymeleaf the if use like this

```
<div  th:if="${s.questionPattern ==q.questionPattern.questionPattern }">
```

there is no need for the `#` symbol.